# RESTful APIs using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am developing REST APIs for my project using Laravel. For every request I am firing a database request to see if the requested api_token exists or not. If not I am giving out a json response saying "Unauthorized access".

```
if( count($user) == 0 ) {

    $toSend['success'] = 0;
    $toSend['response'] = 'Unauthorized access';
}
```

However there is another way to do this. If I just wrap the route with auth:api middleware,

```
Route::post('/address', 'SomeController@someMethod')->middleware('auth:api');
```

it does the same thing without having to make a database request. Should I just go with the middleware process or do both ?? Which one is a good practice?

Comment: Go with middleware process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always go with the middleware and mention the list of apis in the API group list as follows

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
   Route::get('getUser','Testcontroller@getData');
});
```

Comment: ok..so should I just define the logic inside the getData method ? One more question. If the logic somehow fails then how do I handle any kind of exception??

Comment: getUser => API is just a sample API which I have written to understand how the group middleware works. 'auth:api' should contains the logic.                           try {
   $user = JWTAuth::toUser(JWTAuth::getToken());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
             if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException){
                return response()->error('Session is Expired', 401);
            }else{
                return response()->error($e->getMessage(), 200);
            }
        }

Comment: I know it's just an example but my question how do i handle exception while building rest apis. I want my android app to pop up an alert box if exception found.  any suggestions?

Comment: Responds back with the other response code along with the message and display in android app. e.g)                $msg = 'Could not find the Server.';
                    return response()->error($msg);

Comment: Ok. any laravel plugin that you recommend to handle exception??

Comment: nothing like that. create a response service provider, register in config/app and start use in controllers.  due to space constraint I removed the success and given only for error.    Response::macro('error', function ($message, $status = 400) {
            return Response::json([
                'message'         => $status.' error',
                'errors'          => [
                'message'         => [$message],
            ],
                'status_code'     => $status,
            ], $status);
        });